# JSP page not loading issue after login

Tags: javascript, jsp, websphere

JSP page is not loading after login. same set up is working on Quality system but trying to clone on another system its not working.. guessing the images files path are not reachable in custom project. getting 404 error.. using web sphere server &  jdk 1.8

Answer (score 0):

From just your original description it is hard to say what might cause the error, but then if you have reason to believe an image path isn't reachable can you test that theory by logging into the system and seeing if you can access the directory in question.  Generally, whether an error in JSP is caused by a compile error or a runtime error, there should be a message or exception in the server log showing more information what went wrong.